# Como se puede mejorar la compilación de SASS y Bootstrap usando npm?

Tags: css, bootstrap, npm, sass, scss

Para compilar estoy abriendo 2 consolas donde en una ejecuto el script `npm` que escribí para compilar `scss` con `css` y luego otra consola donde compilo `bootstrap.scss` con `bootstrap.css` .
El problema o incomodidad que tengo es que cuando trabajo con bootstrap agregando clases al `index.html` por ejemplo debo ir al archivo `bootstrap.scss` y guardar para que hagan efectos los cambios automáticamente con la extensión liveserver de visual studio code y no sucede lo mismo cuando hago cambios en el archivo `style.scss` ya que guardo y automáticamente compila.

`package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "mizuxe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "website with bootstrap and sass",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass --watch scss -o css",
    "scssbootstrap": "node-sass --watch scss/bootstrap.scss -o css"
  },
  "author": "Joe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar la extension [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) ya que comentas que usas vscode, compila todo el sass del proyecto a la vez, no requiere que tengas ningun paquete de npm instalado, solo la instalas y la activas. Es la forma mas cómoda.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma que podrías hacer para optimizar la forma en como compilas es crear un archivo dentro del folder scss llamado main.scss. Dentro de este archivo, debes importar tus archivos scss `@import 'boostrapstyles', 'mystyles';`. O haces un import para cada uno

```
@import boostrapstyles;
@import mystyles
```

Luego debes hacerle el watch a tu archivo main.scss y listo! Los cambios que hagas en ambos se verán reflejados sin necesidad de guardar en ambos.